# Correctly depicting trends in matplotlib python like spreadsheet charts

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I have a pretty simple dataset containing dates and petrol prices.

That plots like the below image in WPS Spreadsheet

[image]

But the same dataset gets plotted in matplotlib python as follows
[image]

The dataframe on which I am plotting is

```
         date  price
0  2018-05-12  75.09
1  2018-05-13  75.09
2  2018-05-14  75.28
3  2018-05-15  75.42
4  2018-05-16  75.57
5  2018-05-17  75.78
6  2018-05-18  76.06
7  2018-05-19  76.34
8  2018-05-20  76.66
9  2018-05-21  76.98
10 2018-05-22  77.27
11 2018-05-23  77.55
12 2018-05-24  77.84
13 2018-05-25  78.19
14 2018-05-26  78.32
15 2018-05-27  78.46
16 2018-05-28  78.61
17 2018-05-29  78.76
18 2018-05-30  78.19
19 2018-05-31  78.68
20 2018-06-01  78.60
21 2018-06-02  78.51
22 2018-06-03  78.43
23 2018-06-04  78.43
24 2018-06-05  78.16
25 2018-06-06  78.05
26 2018-06-07  77.97
27 2018-06-08  77.77
28 2018-06-09  77.38
29 2018-06-10  77.15
30 2018-06-11  76.96
31 2018-06-12  76.82
32 2018-06-13  76.82
```

Here's my code I am using to plot
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import Datasets as DS

```
df = DS.getDataSet_petrol("13-06-2018")

plt.plot(df['date'],df['price'])

plt.show()
```

Apparently looking the spreadsheet chart shows non-linnear trends while matplotlib shows a linnear trend.

This confuses me about the correct regression model to use linear or polynomial regressions.

So my main question is :
How can I make the python plot look like the spreadsheet one?

Comment: Which version of matplolib are using? Can you indicate the datatypes of these columns?

Comment: ... print(mpl.__version__)
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
2.2.2

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> For both the columns

Comment: Just post the return of `df.dtypes`

Comment: date     datetime64[ns]
price            object
dtype: object

Comment: ok try: `plt.plot(df['date'],df['price'].astype('float')) `

Comment: Wow..it has solved..If you can explain and post that as an answer....@Fourier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is caused by having string objects in your `df["price"]`.

This can be solved by converting it to float prior to plotting it.

```
plt.plot(df['date'],df['price'].astype('float'))
```

Or even before doing anything with the data:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('float')
```